# How do I authorize a non default runtime service account for my cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-iam

I am using terraform to deploy a Google Cloud Function. I have a module for deploying cloud functions which I use like so:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "functions_bucket" {
  name = "${var.project}-functions"
}

module cf {
  source                = "./modules/CloudFunction"
  name                  = "helloworld"
  bucket                = google_storage_bucket.functions_bucket.name
  project               = var.project
  region                = var.region
  service_account_email = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa.email}"
  source_root_dir       = "./cloudFunctions/hello"
  entry_point           = "main"
  runtime               = "python37"
  source_files          = ["main.py","requirements.txt"]
  trigger_http          = true
}
```

*(the module takes care of zipping up the source code for the function and uploading it to a bucket before then creating the functions)*

As can be seen above I am using a non default runtime service account `service_account_email = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa.email}"` which the function will run as. Here is how the service account is defined:

```
resource "google_service_account" "sa" {
  account_id = "dataflowdemo"
}
```

When I run `terraform apply` (i.e. when I want to create these resources in my GCP project) it fails. Here is the output:

> ➜  terraform apply --auto-approve
> module.cf.data.template_file.t_file[1](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration): Refreshing state...
> module.cf.data.template_file.t_file[0]: Refreshing state...
> module.cf.local_file.to_temp_dir[1](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration): Refreshing state... [id=ba8ab5a0280b953aa97435ff8946cbcbb2755a27]
> module.cf.local_file.to_temp_dir[0]: Refreshing state... [id=4f74e1a2f443086112a0beca8bd67308e98b3040]
> google_storage_bucket.functions_bucket: Refreshing state... [id=myproject-functions]
> google_service_account.sa: Refreshing state... [id=projects/myproject/serviceAccounts/dataflowdemo@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
> module.cf.google_storage_bucket_object.archive: Refreshing state... [id=myproject-functions-cloudfunctions/helloworld.f6f6a551ec2a74bbabe74715a20e7c4e.zip]
> module.cf.data.archive_file.archive: Refreshing state...
> module.cf.google_storage_bucket_object.archive: Destroying... [id=myproject-functions-cloudfunctions/helloworld.f6f6a551ec2a74bbabe74715a20e7c4e.zip]
> module.cf.google_storage_bucket_object.archive: Destruction complete after 1s
> module.cf.google_storage_bucket_object.archive: Creating...
> module.cf.google_storage_bucket_object.archive: Creation complete after 0s [id=myproject-functions-cloudfunctions/helloworld.f6f6a551ec2a74bbabe74715a20e7c4e.zip]
> module.cf.google_cloudfunctions_function.HTTPcloudfunction[0]: Creating...

> Error: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid function service account requested: serviceAccount:dataflowdemo@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation., badRequest

I follow the link provided in the error message and find the relevant section for this error message (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#non-default-runtime) which states:

> to use a non-default runtime service account, **the deployer must have the `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` permission on that non-default account**. **A user who creates a non-default runtime service account is automatically granted this permission**, but other deployers must have this permission granted by a user with the correct permissions.

and the solution is to:

> [Assign the user](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration) the `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` role on the non-default runtime service account.

I'm confused why this isn't working because it states:

> A user who creates a non-default runtime service account is automatically granted this permission

and the deployer is me (i.e. my Google account).

Hoping someone here explain to me what I need to do here to make this work. TIA.

The code in its current state is here: https://github.com/jamiekt/dataflowdemo/tree/9c3b22f741dc4a48f6180726a8c032c879787f6e

Comment: Terraform is using a service account. That is different from your identity that you use to login to Google Cloud. Assign the `serviceAccountUser` role to the service account that Terraform is using. The service account is specified under `provider "google"`.

Comment: thanks for the reply John. If you check the source code (link provided above) you will see I am not specifying any service account in the provider declaration. I am authenticating using `gcloud auth application-default login` (as  explained at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started#configuring-the-provider). When I issued that command I authenticated as my Google account.

Comment: I wonder then if the problem here is that the account I am deploying as *must* be a service account, and hence my personal Google account identity won't work.

Comment: Do not use user credentials for tools. Use a service account. Is that your problem? I do not know (not enough information) but it is best to set everything up correctly to prevent future problems which you will have using user credentials.

Comment: that is a good shout indeed.

Comment: I did want to use terraform to deploy everything so there is a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem here. I need a service account to use as the deployment account for terraform but I want to use terraform to create all my resources. I guess I need to create that deployment service account using other means.

Comment: Do you have this environment variable set? `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` Terraform will use that if the no service account is setup in the provider.

Comment: Yes, you have a chicken and egg situation, however you cannot use Terraform to setup your own privileges. Separate your own authorization, the authorization of tools and the privileges of services created by tools.

Comment: good advice, thank you John. And no, I haven't exported GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, right now I'm just using the credentials supplied by `gcloud auth application-default login`. Clearly I need to change to use a dedicated deployment service account, which I am doing right now. Thx again.

Comment: Can confirm you are correct John. Once I created a dedicated deployment service account and granted it the appropriate permissions that I was able to progress.

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution. HashiCorp has very popular software and I hope this thread helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to commenter @John-Hanley who helped out here. I needed to create a dedicated service account for doing deployments as per [Google Provider > Adding credentials](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started#adding-credentials).

```sh
export PROJECT=myproject
gcloud iam service-accounts create --project $PROJECT deployer
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$(pwd)/deployer.json
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create \
   --project $PROJECT \
   --iam-account deployer@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT \
  --member="serviceAccount:deployer@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role="roles/cloudfunctions.admin"
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT \
  --member="serviceAccount:deployer@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role="roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin"
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
    --member="serviceAccount:deployer@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
```